# Retract Close Vote?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

I close voted a question recently and wish to take back, so an option in the "Close" menu should be "Retract vote". It would be a lot faster than flagging a mod. Is there already an option like this and I'm making a fool out of myself (since I can't find it.) Or can there be an option like that?

It could come in handy!

**EDIT; Never mind, there is one, totally missed that!**

Comment: You can retract close votes. Just try to close it again, and the option is now "Retract close votes"

Comment: How on earth did I miss that? Thanks @d'alar'cop

Comment: Probably because it seems counter-intuitive to click "vote to close" in order to do the exact opposite! Maybe you should raise a separate question about that counter-intuitiveness

Comment: @d'alar'cop Done! http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1670/retracting-close-vote-included-in-the-vote-to-close-menu

Comment: This is one of those 'Assumption' puzzles I've heard so much about... :P

Comment: @Damien H Lol. Funny.

Comment: Thanks for this question - I ve missed the United-vote feature as well!

Comment: ...ah, well. Doesn't seem to work from the iPad app... At least you now know where the VTC for this question comes from...